# Deploy multiple agents with dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm developing a dialogflow agent for bookings. My problem is that I need to deploy the agent for multiple clients with their own calendars. Unfortunately on the Google Cloud Platform is possible to have just one agent per project but at the same time the number of project is limited. How can i solve this? I may have 3 solutions but I'm open to suggestions.

1. Ask more projects to Google and associate each project to each of my clients. I will be able to manage the projects with a service account. But how much will it cost? May I request like more than 1000 projects?
2. Create a new Google Cloud Platform account for every client and create a project for each account (Like the qwicklabs account in the google courses). The problem is that I don't know how to scale this solution since I'd need to automate this process and i don't want to create an account manually each time.
3. Use the same GCP account and the same agent for multiple clients. This may require to insert a unique code when starting the chat to identify to which calendar we are referring. In this way though I won't be able to integrate the chat on the client's website or facebook page unless I don't give the same credentials to everyone.

What do you think could be the best solution? Do you have any other ideas to solve this problem?

Thank you guys

Comment: How did you manage to solve this? My aim is to resell the same bot to multiple customers, but I need to identify them firstly. Did you give the same credentials or created a database with customer ids?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the best solution, it would best to create a project for each client. As for when using [dialogflow products](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/multi-project), Each project can have at most one agent, so you need multiple projects if you need multiple agents either way.

Additionally, when it comes to the amount of projects you can have in GCP, the limit for the average user is 30 projects. However, you can always increase the amount of projects by requesting a higher limit. You can do so by referencing this document [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas).